# kubectl YAML config file equivalent of "kubectl run ... -i --tty ..."

Tags: yaml, kubernetes, interactive, kubectl

I've been using "kubectl run" with assorted flags to run Jobs interactively, but have recently outgrown what I can do with those flags, and have graduated to using YAML config files to describe my jobs.

However, I can't find an equivalent to the "-i" and "--tty" flags, to attach to the Job I'm creating.

Is there an equivalent YAML spec for:

```
kubectl run myjob \
            -i \
            --tty \
            --image=grc.io/myproj/myimg:mytag \
            --restart=Never \
            --rm \
            -- \
            my_command
```

Or is this maybe not the right approach?

Answer (score 51):

I think you are mentioning these fields.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L2081-L2088

You can define `stdin` and `tty` in yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: test 
spec: 
  containers: 
    - name: test 
      image: test 
      stdin: true 
      tty: true
```

Comment: can you give an example yaml file showing how to do this? I find that it isn't clear from the type definitions.

Comment: IIUC, just add "stdin: true" and "tty: true" to your container spec. For example: 
```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: test
      stdin: true
      tty: true
 ```
 Oops, I can't write things with multiple lines in comment. Hope you could understand, :P

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Lantao.  However, in my case I'm looking at doing this specifically for a Job.  If I put the `tty` and `stdin` fields in the `template` spec for the Pods _within_ the Job, they appear to have no effect.  I can actually sort of understand that by the usage model.

Comment: After further experimentation, `tty` and `stdin` don't have the effect I'd hoped even in plain old Pod specs, as shown in Lantao's example (at least on k8s 1.2.4 as currently deployed on GKE).

Comment: After creating the pods, you can run [`kubectl attach POD -c CONTAINER`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/1d96b4c55b6b4e6bc9bda5d12a7b99834056bdf4/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_attach.md) to attach to the container.

Comment: `tty` and `stdin` are just equivalent configuration to  `-i` and `--tty`. However, to attach a pod, you need to do what @Yu-JuHong mentioned. :)

Comment: It's the attach that matters here.  When you do it in `kubectl run` we automatically attach

Comment: how can I run command once with kubectl-run by specifying yaml config file?

Comment: To attach to the pod, I had to also provide `-i` and `-t` to the kubectl attach command as well, so the full command was `kubectl attach POD [ -c CONTAINER ] -i -t` - Note: -c CONTAINER is optional if you only have one container - it'll just default to that.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Lantao's answer with a `kubectl run` one liner using the `--overrides` flag in json format:

```
kubectl run nodejs --image=node:lts-alpine --rm -i --quiet --overrides='{
    "kind": "Pod",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nodejs"
    },
    "spec": {
        "volumes": [
            {
                "name": "host-volume",
                "hostPath": {
                    "path": "/home/Sources/df-sdc/web/themes/custom/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "nodejs",
                "image": "busybox",
                "stdin": true,
                "tty": true,
                "workingDir": "/app",
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "name": "host-volume",
                        "mountPath": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "FallbackToLogsOnError",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
            }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "securityContext": {
            "runAsUser": 1000,
            "runAsGroup": 1000
        }
    }
}
'
```