# kubectl exec returning `Handshake status 500`

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm using python kubernetes 3.0.0 library and kubernetes 1.6.6 on AWS.

I have pods that can disappear quickly. Sometimes when I try to exec to them I get ApiException `Handshake status 500` error status.

This is happening with `in cluster configuration` as well as `kube config`.

When pod/container doesn't exist I get `404` error which is reasonable but `500` is `Internal Server Error`. I don't get any `500` errors in `kube-apiserver.log` where I do find `404` ones.

What does it mean and can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this question is a little old, but I thought I would share what I found when trying to use python/kubernetes attach/exec for several debugging cases (since this isn't documented anywhere I can find).

As far as I can tell, it's all about making the keyword arguments match the actual container configuration as opposed to what you want the container to do.

When creating pods using `kubectl run`, if you don't use `-i --tty` flags (indicating interactive/TTY allocation), and then attempt to set either the `tty` or `stdin` flags to `True` in your function, then you'll get a mysterious 500 error with no other debug info. If you need to use `stdin` and `tty` and you are using a configuration file (as opposed to run), then make sure you [set the `stdin` and `tty` flags to `true` in `spec.containers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559704/kubectl-yaml-config-file-equivalent-of-kubectl-run-i-tty).

While running `resp.readline_stdout()`, if you get a `OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t`, set the keyword argument `timeout=<any integer>`. By default, the timeout variable defaults to None, which is an invalid value in that function.

If you run the attach/exec command and get an APIException and a status code of 0, the error `Reason: hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match either of...`, note that there appears to be an incompatibility with Python 2. Works in Python 3. Should be patched eventually.

I can confirm 404 code is thrown via an ApiException when the pod doesn't exist.

If you are getting a mysterious error saying `upgrade request required`, note that you need to use the `kubernetes.stream.stream` function to wrap the call to attach/exec. You can see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/409) and [this example code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/exec.py) to help you get past that part.

Here's my example: `resp = kubernetes.stream.stream(k8s.connect_get_namespaced_pod_attach, name='alpine-python-2', namespace="default", stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=True, _preload_content=False)`

Note that the `_preload_content=False` is essential in the `attach` command or else the call will block indefinitely.

I know that was probably more information than you wanted, but hopefully at least some of it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was,
I had two pods, with same label attached, 1 pod was in **Evicted** state and other was running , i deleted that pod, which was **Evicted** and issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

For me, The reason for 500 was basically pod unable to pull the image from GCR