# How to keep docker pod without entrypoint running in K8S?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8 as build
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
```

publish to our artifactory. However, as there is no command / entrypoint provided, the docker would simply end immediately. so I usually use `docker run -d -t` to run it. However, when deploying it in kubernetes, I cannot specify the `args` -d and -t since I will get an error that node does not know the arguments -d and -t.

When adding the following entrypoint,

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

The machine keeps crashing

How can I keep the pod running in background?

Comment: How you run that docker image on k8s. Are you using kubectl run command ?

Comment: it is deployed by a yaml file and kubectl apply

Comment: Why do you want it to be running? What should it do?

Comment: it is a protractor test machine that will start the protractor as a kubernetes job as soon as the test environment is start up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `-i` and `--tty` option of `kubectl run` command.

```
kubectl run -i --tty --image=<image> <name> --port=80 --env="DOMAIN=cluster"
```

More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/#docker-run).

**Update:**

In case of yaml files make use of `stdin` and `tty` option.

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: testpod
spec: 
  containers: 
    - name: testpod
      image: testimage
      stdin: true
      tty: true
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559704/kubectl-yaml-config-file-equivalent-of-kubectl-run-i-tty).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same case. Besides

```
      stdin: true
      tty: true
```

I also need to add:

```
      command:
        - /bin/bash
```